# What is the name of this graph?

Tags: data-visualization

What is the name of this type of graph?

It shows the customer flow between mobile device manufacturers. Source: [Deloitte report](http://www2.deloitte.com/content/dam/Deloitte/nl/Documents/technology-media-telecommunications/deloitte-nl-tmt-global-mobile-consumer-survey-2014.pdf)

[image: Graph]

Comment: Does it? I'm having trouble seeing what it is showing, and I posted another question in hopes of more detailed explanation than could be provided here. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141027/how-to-read-this-variable-width-chord-diagram

Comment: @xan +1 for questioning the actual informative value of the graph.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I didn't know before I saw your question but I remember that I saw such a graph in [the d3.js gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery). This is called a [chord diagram](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006).

Answer (score 1):

I saw this graph in some biological papers. It is called circos. Originally, it was proposed in [this](http://genome.cshlp.org/content/early/2009/06/15/gr.092759.109.full.pdf+html) article:

Krzywinski, M. et al. Circos: an Information Aesthetic for Comparative Genomics. Genome Res (2009) 19:1639-1645.

Comment: From your link, it seems that Circos is the name of a package which can generate similar plots, not the name of the plot itself.